# Unsure how to prove this inequality used in Brownian motion proof?

Tags: inequality, brownian-motion, fractals, integral-inequality, geometric-inequalities

I am reading through a proof that a Brownian motion trail almost surely has dimension $1 \frac{1}{2}$. While attempting to derive a lower bound for the dimension they use this inequality:

$(x^2 + h^2)^{-s/2} \leq x^{-s} + h^{-s}$

Where it is assumed that $1 < s < 2$.

It doesn't seem that complicated an inequality, but I'm not sure how to prove it, or even make a heuristic argument to justify it.

**Edit: It seems I misread. The actual inequality they used is as follows:**

$\int_0^\infty (x^2 + h^2)^{-s/2} dx \leq \int_0^h h^{-s} dx + \int_h^\infty x^{-s} dx$

Comment: Are you sure you aren't missing a factor of $1/2$ inside the parentheses? If so it's pretty straightforward. Just use the fact that they split the integral into the region where $x\le h$ and where $x\ge h.$

Comment: Just double checked and not that I can see.

Comment: @Patty Actually your inequality holds if reversed

Comment: Whoops I misread anyway. Think it still goes through though.

Comment: @Patty maybe they have introduced a notation for $ \leq $ if one side is bigger than the other by perhaps a correction by a constant factor

Comment: Not that I've read so far. The book in question is 'Fractal Geometry' by Kenneth Falconer. The proof is on page 284 (for my edition anyway). There is a factor of $ch^{1/2-s}$ but it appears in front of both sides of the inequality.

Comment: @Patty Yes it looks like it is a typo, but not an important one since he wants the inequality to hold up to a constant factor which as it was mentioned by speceisdarker is true.

Comment: I see, that makes sense given he goes on to update $c$ to $c_1$ in the next line.

Comment: @clark Think it holds literally, not up to a constant. Was confused before. See answer below.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen right the exponent is negative!

Comment: @clark Sorry shoulda spelled it out clearly instead of letting it infect you too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $s>0$ have both $$ \frac{1}{(x^2+h^2)^{s/2}}  \le \frac{1}{x^s}$$ and $$ \frac{1}{(x^2+h^2)^{s/2}}  \le \frac{1}{h^s}$$

so we can replace the integrand by either of these in the inequality.

The reason they split it up like and choose a different inequality for each that is so that both the integrals converge.